# How to update/change the Interface of already registered COM in C#

Tags: c#, deployment, interface, com

I have created a user Control in C# (as a class library). Now I have registered the class (using `regasm`) and I can use this control on a `VBA` user-form. All the methods,events and properties works as expected. But When I am trying to add new methods to the Interface, I can't see them in VBA. Is it possible to update an already registered COM's interface?

If yes, can you please provide some guidance.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either, so I upvoted to balance matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

COM interfaces are generally considered immutable. The "correct" way is to create a new interface `IWhatever2` that extends your existing `IWhatever` that has the new methods.

However, if you haven't released this yet (i.e. it's still in development and you're the only one using it), you can essentially delete and replace the interface. You'll need to unregister the existing interface (`regasm /u`) and give your "new" interface a new GUID and register it again.

Comment: yes, its in dev phase only.As I can't add and test new features its very frustrating too. I will give it a try tomorrow and update. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: He does not need to give it a new GUID.  He's in development.  That's overkill and completely unnecessary.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson, probably not, but since nothing is relying on that GUID it won't do any harm either.